# Trying to use jms publisher/subscriber in jmeter to connect to IBM MQ

Tags: jmeter, ibm-mq

We have been using jms point-to-point sampler in jmeter to post an xml based request to the MQ. Since then our application has changed and now the messages that are posted to the MQ are Serialable objects created with spring integration. To have a test around this, we tried using jms publisher/subscriber. All the online support we tried is pointing to connection to ActiveMQ. Has anyone tried using jms published to post object message to and IBM MQ?

Comment: If using the jar files separately and you want IBM to support it, please read [Obtaining the WebSphere MQ classes for JMS](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21683398) for instructions on how to obtain and install the jar-only package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The online approach gives you all the elements to switch to IBM MQ.

You would need to:

1. put IBM MQ jars in lib folder of jmeter
2. Find the infos needed for :

   - http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JMS_Subscriber
   - http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JMS_Publisher

This will help you:

- http://leakfromjavaheap.blogspot.com/2014/07/jmeter-and-websphere-mq-series.html?_sm_au_=iVV5P5vR626sDt7V